# JS arrays shifting elements around

Tags: javascript, object

I'm not that good when it comes to JS arrays/objects, so I have the following at the moment:

```
{
    "rows":{
        "0":{
            "type":"row",
            "width_class":"row new_row",
            "column_class":"one"
        },
        "1":{
            "type":"row",
            "width_class":"row new_row",
            "column_class":"two"
        },
        "2":{
            "type":"row",
            "width_class":"row new_row",
            "column_class":"three"        
        }
    }

}
```

Now what I'm trying to accomplish, is move the rows around, for example move "1" to position "0" and then re-do the keys so so their from 0 to what ever is the total count(-1).

Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: Your data structure doesn't look right, you probably want an array, so you'd have to fix the source that generates the data, then you can simply use array methods to manipulate the position of elements. Note that object keys don't have an order.

Comment: Hmm, but then when I go to stringify it to a JSON string, it doesnt include them

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius: see my answer and the jsFiddle that goes with it (http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/PZKZ9/). You *can* stringify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Array.splice() API](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the first one element.

Comment: Doesn't work on objects. Altho I changed the type to array for data = [] and my old code(with splice) works just fine

Comment: If you want to delete object's property, use `delete` keyword, e.g. `delete obj.rows[0]`, then the obj will leave 1 and 2 only.

Answer (score 1):

If your object looks like this:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
        "type":"row",
        "width_class":"row new_row",
        "column_class":"one"
    },
    {
        "type":"row",
        "width_class":"row new_row",
        "column_class":"two"
    },
    {
        "type":"row",
        "width_class":"row new_row",
        "column_class":"three"        
    }
  ]
};
```

You can use Array methods to drag around the elements of `[yourobj].rows`.

Here's [**a JsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/PZKZ9/) of that